# Почему цикл вывода статей работает только на 1 странице?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="card-page">
        <div class="card-info">
          <h3><?php the_tags(); ?></h3>
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
          <span><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
          <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Здравствуйте. С помощью данного кода вывожу статьи на главной странице, и все работает, но когда я хочу использовать этот же код на другой странице ничего не выводится. Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Может инклуда какого не хватает?

Comment: Даже если я полностью скопирую код главной и вставлю в эту страницу (то есть заменю) все равно не работает

Comment: Значит страница эта не где не регнута в хуках.

Comment: Значит вызываемых функций нет в области видимости. Какая ошибка?

Comment: Что за "другая страница"? Вы просто создаёте php-файл и пытаетесь запустить в нём этот код или пользуетесь правилом иерархии шаблонов в WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте файл mypage.php в корень папки с активной темой (например, wp-content/themes/mytheme/mypage.php) со следующим содержимым:

```
<?php /* Template Name: MyPage */ ?>
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <div class="card-page">
        <div class="card-info">
          <h3><?php the_tags(); ?></h3>
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
          <span><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
          <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Далее в админке создайте/отредактируйте страницу и в качестве шаблона укажите MyPage. Все должно отработать